# Angularjs ui-gmap-window object data not rendering

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I have and issue with my ui-gmap-window in angularjs.
The problem is getting the object data into the window as it wont seem to render.

this is my mark-up:

```
        <ui-gmap-window coords="selectedmarker.coords" options="windowOptions" closeClick="closeClick()" show="windowOptions.show">
            <div style="overflow: auto; width: 300px;">
                <h2 style="font-size: 12px">{{selectedmarker.title}}</h2>
                <h2 style="font-size: 12px">ADRESS:</h2>
                <span>{{selectedmarker.addressStreet}}</span>
                <br/>
                <span>{{selectedmarker.addressZip + ' ' + selectedmarker.addressCity}}</span><br/>
                <span>{{'Telefon: ' + selectedmarker.phoneNumber}}</span><br/>
                <span>{{'E-postadress: ' + selectedmarker.email}}</span>
                <h2 style="font-size: 12px">ÅTERFÖRSÄLJARE AV:</h2>
                <span>{{selectedmarker.products}}</span>
            </div>
        </ui-gmap-window>
        <ui-gmap-markers click="'onClick'" models="retailersService.foundRetailers.retailers" coords="'coords'" icon="'icon'" idKey="id">

        </ui-gmap-markers>
```

and this is my angular:

```
 $scope.selectedmarker = {};

    $scope.onClick = function (data) {
    $scope.windowOptions.show = !$scope.windowOptions.show;
    $scope.selectedmarker = data; 
};
//call the on-click-funcionality with my collection of objects.
    $scope.addMarkerClickFunction(mycollection);

//On-click-functionality
   $scope.addMarkerClickFunction = function (mycollection) {
    angular.forEach(mycollection, function (value, key) {
        value.onClick = function () {
            $scope.onClick(value);
        };
    });
};
```

When I console.log my "Selectedmarker" object it has all the data it should have. however nothing renders in my ui-gmap-window.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Were u able to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Another post popped up with a similar problem and all that was missing was calling, $scope.$apply() after setting a value to my "selectedmarker"

Comment: im having the same problem. still not working with $apply()